# Appium: Visual Studio Android Emulator:

Tags: visual-studio, appium, appium-android

Appium: Visual Studio Android Emulator: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx

I am looking to use appium for mobile testing using C#. I had a look into below articles and followed the mentioned steps.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ganesh/2016/03/13/browser-appium-visualstudio/

When I reached the point to download visual studio emulator I received the below error.

Visual studio Emulator error screenshot:
[image]

So does it mean I can't install emulator in Win 7 PC? and can't use Appium with C# for mobile testing in win 7?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check [System Requirements for the Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx). 
It says that you must have win 8 or higher in order to install this + 6GB of Ram and should be of 64 bit OS.

Please upgrade your PC and install again. It should solve the issue.

Comment: Actually I read that previously. What I tried to ask in question was, now that I have win 7 I can't use Appium with C#. Is there a work around with Win 7

Comment: @AhetejazahmadKhan:  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html . This can run on win7, but not sure if it can help you.